# AngularJS - Scope is not what expected inside an ng-click event of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-controller

I have this code snippet:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="message in messages">
        <button ng-click="send()">Send</button>
    </li>
</ul>

$scope.send = function(){
    // not working (message undefined)
    alert($scope.message.text);
    // working 
    alert($scope.messages[0].text);
};
```

I do not understand why:

```
alert($scope.message.text);
```

does not work. I thought that ng-repeat was creating a new scope.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its true that `ng-repeat` creates a new scope. But you cannot access that scope by doing $scope inside your controller. Instead you can do as below:

```
<button ng-click="send(message)">Send</button>
```

And in your JS:

```
$scope.send = function(message){    
    alert(message.text);    
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Could you explain a bit this behavior? Why do I get this scope instead of the other scope?

Comment: @poiuytrez You cannot access the scope of `ng-repeat` inside the controller by doing $scope. Instead you can pass the object from inside ng-repeat to the controller :)

Answer (score -1):

That Message access only local side that is view side(index.html). Dosn,t access controller side. But message is passed arguments that is send(message).